# EventStore DuplicateCommit Query

Tags: neventstore

Why does the SQL persistence for @Jonathan Oliver's EventStore use `CommitSequence` as one of the criteria for detecting a duplicate commit? Why wouldn't `StreamId` and `CommitId` be sufficient?

See the SQL below.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Commits
WHERE StreamId = @StreamId
  AND CommitSequence = @CommitSequence
  AND CommitId = @CommitId
```

This SQL statement is from `SqlPersistenceEngine.DetectDuplicate()`. It's used to determine if a `DuplicateCommitException` should be thrown or just a `ConcurrencyException`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your SQL is about.

The reason the CommitSequence participates in the unique indexes is if 2 people are writing are modifying v5 at the same time, one might write a v6 with 1 event and another writes a v6 with a different event.

In some cases, all writers have a common source of Commit Ids, but quite often (and Common Domain does this), one just generates a random `Guid` as the Commit Id and in that case you still want the conflict to be detected.

I guess one could abuse GUIDs to create a fixed sequence that encodes the StreamVersion (v6 above) to generate the Commit Id to make it redundant but for me it's pretty clearly needed and useful.

Be sure to read the readme in the NuGet package BTW - most of this stuff is explained pretty well IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your input Ruben. The SQL statement I listed is from SqlPersistenceEngine.DetectDuplicate. This statement is used to determine if a DuplicateCommitException should be thrown or just a ConcurrencyException. It seems to me that the distinction is detection of duplicate message processing vs. concurrent aggregate changes. But if this is the case, I don't understand why CommitSequence is part of the query. My commit Ids comes from my messages.

Comment: @Joe much better now. If it is the same commit, it can be dropped on the floor. If it is not, then the Conflict Resolution hooks in Common Domain allow one to decide based on a customizable strategy of your choosing whether they are equivalent before deciding to roll back or not. That's the principle but to be honest I've never implemented such a conflict management piece so I won't venture any further into explaining exactly why it's **exactly** the way it is. Hope someone has the answer from the horse's mouth for you soon!